# Until loop-- why doesn't it exit immediately?

Tags: ruby

Question: with the first line in the "until" loop, we set the boolean, sorted, to true. Why does the loop even run after this line? Also why can we not put sorted = true after the .times do loop (to close the until sorted loop) and achieve the same result?

```
def bubble_sort(arr)
  len = arr.length
  sorted = false
  until sorted
    sorted = true
    (len-1).times do |i|
      if arr[i] > arr[i+1]
        arr[i],arr[i+1] = arr[i+1],arr[i]
        sorted = false
      end
    end
  end
  arr
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this: `lives = 1; until lives == 10 do; puts "Watch out!"; 
(lives == 9) ? puts("Egad! I've had nine!") : puts("Whew, that was close, that's number #{lives}"); lives += 1; end; puts "Meooowwwww"`.

Comment: Until and while are very closely related, but I think they are diverging lately.  The experience relayed here does not match that in the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/files/keywords_rb.html#M000038).  If the conditional statement is false, according to the documentation, it should not process the block.  That is, unless it is the modifier form, as in the `begin..end until false` form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop condition is checked at the beginning of each iteration through the loop. The value of `sorted` inside the loop body doesn't matter, all that matters is the value of `sorted` when the loop is about to start another iteration. The loop isn't watching `sorted` to see when its value changes, it just evaluates `sorted` before each iteration and stops the looping when it is truthy (i.e. not `false` and not `nil`) when it is checked.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now! sorted = true by default unless there is a single number out of place.